# Is there a way to speed up/give more resources to a single query?

Tags: mysql

For 3 days I have the following query running:

```
alter table pois modify column id bigint(12) not null;
```

with the purpose to change the type from int(11) to bigint(12) and remove AUTO_INCREMENT on a table with 600.000.000 rows (40gb).

According the processlist the progress is now at: 31,4 with the status "copy to tmp table".

Is there any way to give more resources/speed up this process temporarily? Or is there a way to execute this query without backing up the table?

Comment: Sometimes it’s faster to just create a new table and insert stuff there, especially if it already needs to copy data to a temporary table. But there’s no real rule that I know of

Comment: `ALTERing` the `PRIMARY KEY` necessarily requires a copy.  Removing `AUTO_INCREMENT` seems unnecessary; what was your rationale?

Comment: @RickJames      i wanted to remove auto_increament because i decided to use own unique values for id based on a formula, this requires altering the table with bigint. But its true i could keep auto_increament.
So should i stop the query, try to remove the column (id, primary key) and readd with bigint ? Would that be faster ?

Comment: Depends on the version of MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames     10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 ; libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.29. The query got stopped anyway as my provider moved my vps to another host to increase performance.

Comment: MariaDB has 7 versions after 10.1; recommend you plan to upgrade some time soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT(12) NOT NULL" D=your_database,t=your_table
```

Percona Toolkit provides a tool called "pt-online-schema-change" that can be used to make non-blocking schema changes

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT(12) NOT NULL, ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
```

MySQL's ALTER TABLE statement allows you to specify the ALGORITHM option